# PHP copy and unlink being ignored

Tags: php, copy, unlink

This code runs when a user hits a delete button on my form. I am trying to copy a file, $picfile, from "/pics/" to "/pics/deletedrecordpics/" and then delete the orginal. Finally, delete the record from the database. Deleting the record from the databse works, but copying the file and deleting the original does nothing. There are no errors in the error log, so I am really confused as to why this code isn't running as I think it should.

```
if ($allowdelete==true && $thepassword == $password)
{
    //delete record that delete was set to by button

    //$sql = ("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$id");
    $sql = ("select picfile,title,author from $table where id=$delete");
    $file=mysql_query($sql);
    $resrow = mysql_fetch_row($file);
    $picfile = $resrow[0];
    $title = $resrow[1];
    $author = $resrow[2];
    if (file_exists("/pics".$picfile)){
        copy("/pics/".$picfile,"/pics/deletedrecordpics/".$author."-".$title."-".$picfile);
        unlink("/pics/".$picfile);
        echo $available = "image is available.";

        $sql = ("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$delete");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($result){
            echo "Your Picture has been removed from our system.";
            Die($available);
        }
        else{
            echo "There was an error in removing your picture.";
            $Delete = "";
            Die();
        }       
    }
    else{
        echo $available = "image is not available.";
    }
}
```

The weird part is a have almost the same code in a delete button on my control panel located in "/adminpanel" and it works perfectly. The code for that is the same except I use $id instead $delete and "../" before all the "pics/" because it's in the adminpanel folder. The permissions are right and the folder exists because the code works with that page. And I know $delete is getting set because the record gets deleted from the database. I know picfile, author and title are getting set because I appended them to the print statement and they were all right. Really confused. Any ideas?

Here is the code for the working page

```
q = ("select picfile,title,author from $table where id=$id");
$file=mysql_query($q);
$resrow = mysql_fetch_row($file);
$picfile = $resrow[0];
$title = $resrow[1];
$author = $resrow[2];
copy("../pics/".$picfile,"../pics/deletedrecordpics/".$author." - ".$title." -     ".$picfile);
unlink("../pics/".$picfile);
$file=mysql_query($q);
$q = ("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$id");
$file=mysql_query($q);
```

Comment: Try to use complete physical path of the file you want to copy or unlink. Batter to use **$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]** followed by directory path of your file i.e. **$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/pics/".$picfile**

Comment: No luck... It's almost like the copy and unlink functions are being ignored or something. I can't think of any reason why. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: These are the core functions of the PHP and can not be ignored just like that. have you tried to find out whether image is available or not using **file_exists()** function (http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) ?

Comment: I edited my question with the new code. How is it possible that it just prints "Your Picture has been removed from our system.Thank you" How does $success not have a value?

Comment: Would you please use die() with some text message that says image is available or not available instead of using **$success** ?

Comment: Made another edit... Somehow $available isn't getting set at all and it just displays "Your Picture has been removed from our system." How can that be?

Comment: Your code block is pretty messy and it seems like you are not following proper conditional check, which is creating more confusion. I Edited your code. Mainly rearranged conditional checking. Please try this edited code. I have noticed that your working code has **"../pics/"** as path. Make sure you use same one in edited code

Comment: your edited code gives me syntax error, unexpected end of file, can't find why?

Comment: And the working code is in a different file, in the folder "/adminpanel" where as the nonworking is already in just "/" so the .. is not needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45902/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-alex-bridges)

Comment: Did you add enough debugging? None of these function will silently fail. Please enable error_reporting and display_errors. Then add various echos and var_dumps to see which part is executed and which is not. There is NO problem in existance that cant be found with more debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/pics/";
if (file_exists($file_path.$picfile))
{
    copy($file_path.$picfile, $file_path."/deletedrecordpics/".$author."-".$title."-".$picfile);
    unlink($file_path.$picfile);
}
else
{
        echo "File not found!!!!!!!!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why is this line repeated twice $file=mysql_query($q); ?

Comment: Good find. I have since removed that, but it wasn't the problem.